# Sampling Distribution/Probability

Tags: probability

A survey was conducted of graduates from $30$ MBA programs.  On the basis of the survey, assume that the mean annual salary for male and female graduates 10 years after graduation is $\$168,000$ and $\$117,000$, respectively.  Assume the standard deviation for the male graduates is $\$40,000$, and for the female graduates it is $\$25,000$.

- **Question 1**: What is the probability that a simple random sample of $40$ male graduates will provide a sample mean within $\$10,000$ of the population mean, $\$168,000$?
- **Question 2**: What is the probability that a simple random sample of $40$ female graduates will provide a sample mean within $\$10,000$ of the population mean of $\$117,000$?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is the distribution of the sample mean. If the sample mean is denoted by $\bar X$, $\text{E}(X)=\mu$ and $\text{V}(X)=\sigma^2$ then $\bar X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.

For this problem let $X$ represent the salary for a male and $Y$ the salary for a female. Let $k=10000$, $n=40$.

$\text{E}(X)=\mu_M=168000$, $\text{V}(X)=\sigma_M^2=40000^2$

$\text{E}(Y)=\mu_F=117000$, $\text{V}(Y)=\sigma_F^2=25000^2$

Then in order to do problem 1 you basically want to calculate:

\begin{align}
\Pr\{X \in [\mu_M-k,\mu_M+k]\}&=\Pr\{ X\leq \mu_M+k  \} - \Pr\{X\leq \mu_M-k\} \\ 
                            &= \Phi\left(\frac{\mu_M+k -\mu_M}{\sigma_M/\sqrt{n}}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{\mu_M-k -\mu_M}{\sigma_M/\sqrt{n}}\right) \\
                            &=2 \Phi\left(\frac{k}{\sigma_M/\sqrt{n}}\right) - 1
\end{align}

Just replace in the numbers and you'll find your answer. Same exact thing for F just different numbers.